# Probability of drawing atleast a pair of identical cards from two sets of cards

Tags: probability

I was given the following problem:

> There are two factory new, identical sets of 52 cards. We shuffle one of the sets (set A) and put them both face down on the table. Then we repeatedly draw both top cards together until we drew every card. What is the probability of getting a pair of identical cards atleast once?

A hint was to use inclusion-exclusion.
*My idea*: We associate to each card in the deck  that was not shuffled (deck B) a number $i$, say in the order they lie on the table. Let $A_i$ be the event that card $i$ is drawn in the $i$-th turn. Then $P(A_i)=\prod_{k=1}^{i-1}\dfrac{52-k}{52-k+1}\cdot\dfrac{1}{52-i+1}$.
But doing this for all the unions and intersections of the $A_i$ would get ugly, so I dont think this is the best way to go about this.

I appreciate any tips!

Comment: Can't you do this by calculating the probability that all cards are on another place, say $P[\text{shuffled}]$, and then simply take $1-P[\text{shuffled}]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
This problem is similar to hat check problem.

The probability that none of the cards are the same $= \frac{!52}{52!} = \frac{2.9672*10^{67}}{8.0658*10^{67}} = 0.3678$

Probability that atleast one is identical $= 1 -  0.3678 =0.6321$

Comment: What is the !52 symbol called?

Comment: derangement is notated by (!n)

Comment: Thank you. Your comment made me recall the proof for the derangement number using inclusion exclusion.

Comment: You are welcome